# Angular ng-repeat over 2 rows

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I currently have two rows with 2 `SPAN` on each one.
What I'd like to do is replace these hardcoded `DIV` and `SPAN` with an `ng-repeat` directive.

My problem is either my 4 `SPAN` go over 4 rows or they all go on the same one.

Is this feasible with Angular.js?

I read stuff on `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end` but I'm not sure this could help me here.

Here's a Plunker for you: http://plnkr.co/edit/DEf2JSTFDBvDXusJDsX7?p=preview

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
I used `SPAN` in my Plunker example for the sake of simplicity but in my real world problem, I'm using a bootstrap grid and I have, in fact, 2 `<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">` in each `<div class="row">`. I hope that clarifies things enough.

Comment: You have included the bootstrap tag... would you be interested in a solution using bootstrap?

Comment: so, update your plunker and add bootstrap there..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple with bootstrap:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6" ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3,4]">
    {{i}}
  </div>
</div>
```

You can even set the width of the wrapper div, if you do not want it to be 100%.

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/J0bKs0BeGW7ltqtnQbNC?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Not nice but works

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3,4]" ng-if="$even"><span>{{i}}</span><span>{{i+1}}</span></div>
```

Solution depends on what u want achieve

Another option is to organize your data not in flat array but as array of arrays

```
[
  [1,2],
  [3,4],
  [5],
]
```

And make ng-repeat in ng-repeat

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="i in myArray">
     <span ng-repeat="j in i">{{j}}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that the solution that would work best for me. But unfortunately, I still have a repetition here...

Comment: I updated my answer, you can check this, that allows u to make as much columns as u want

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use $even and $odd property of ng-repeat.

```
<div class="row">
    <span ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3,4,5,6]">{{i}}
      <br ng-if="$odd">
    </span>
  </div>
```

OR,

```
 <div class="row">
        <span ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3,4,5,6]">{{i}}
          <br ng-if="$index%2===1">
        </span>
      </div>
```

Comment: Thanks but that wouldn't work with bootstrap grid. See my edit for more details.

Answer (score 0):

If your html looks like:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">
     <span>1</span>
     <span>2</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">
     <span>3</span>
     <span>4</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then you can consider doing this with ng-repeat[no `<br>` needed]

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12" ng-repeat="i in [1,3]">
    <span >{{i}}</span>
    <span >{{i+1}}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope it solves your purpose.